# Light wave bending due to magnetic/ electric fields

Tags: visible-light, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I'm new here, but I was wondering, if light is oscillating magnetic and electric fields, how come a powerful magnet can't disrupt, or bend light?  Would it require an electromagnet oscillating at the same frequency of the light to be bent?
How are the gamma rays sent from the sun bent away from the earth?

Answer (score 3):

The equations of classical electrodynamics obey the *superposition principle* - the fields produced by a combination of sources are just the sum of the fields that would be produced by the individual sources in isolation.

So if you have something that makes light, and a magnet, well, they'll both produce the fields they would have produced otherwise, and the overall fields will just be the sum of the two. The two do not talk to each other at all.

This works the exact same way as light and other light. If you shine two beams of light across each other, then each beam still comes out the other side.

What may be a source of confusion is the fact that you know magnets exert forces on each other, but that isn't because the fields interact with each other - it's because the fields interact with the *sources*. So it's true that, for instance, in principle a magnet wiggles a tiny bit at a really high frequency as light passes through it. But this is a different matter.

Comment: That said, in the presence of a medium, the [Faraday effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect) can break this property, with the magnetic field rotating the polarization of the light. It is much harder to actually bend the light, but it is in principle possible through the [Kerr effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_effect) - again, in the presence of a nontrivial medium.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty this is still superposition, no?  Not interaction . two laser beams show interference patterns due to superposition, not to photon-photon interaction. superposition carries over to the quantum description.

Comment: @annav No, neither of those situations obeys the superposition principle. (In the Kerr lensing, in particular, you could have two orthogonal beams cause each other to focus more tightly - this isn't an interference effect.) It's entirely up to you whether you want to call it "interaction", but both effects require a nonlinear medium.

Answer (score 2):

A magnetic field can only affect charged particule, and photons have no charge at all: their trajectory can't be modifiedd by a magnet.

Yet, thanks to a quantum effect called the Delbrück scattering, light can be bent by electromagnetic waves, but the deflection is so tiny that we cannot measure it. In short, for a really short time, a photon can disintegrate into an electron and a positron, which are affected by electromagnetic field: thus, light is bent. This effect has been observed for the first time in 1997 (see [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.79.1626)): collisions of a 46.6 GeV electrons beam with terawatt pulses from a laser produced a signal of about 100 positrons...

Comment: Maybe include an order of magnitude estimate of the effect? To make clear that we're not talking about "one tesla" strong, but "particle physics" strong.

Comment: can a strong enough EM field change the metric and thereby "bend" the path of a low energy EM wave?

Answer (score 1):

Light does bend in strong electromagnetic fields via the vacuum polarization effect. The polarization effect appears as a refractive index and the light passing through the fields behaves as if it is in a dielectric medium. The bending angle in a Coulomb filed is calculated in https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1134

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field can interact with the magnetic moment of the magnet, but this will be relativistically small effect.

So a photon can scatter from magnetic moment (the magnetic field interact with the magnetic moment) the same way photon scatters form charge (electric field interacts with charge). But your question implies bending the light which I am not sure if it could occur.

Answer (score -1):

**Rotation of light's field components**

A well designed for visible light polarizer foil let through approximately 50% of the incomming light. A second polarizer foil placed behind the first foil, but rotated by 90°, would not let through any of the now polarized light.

If you try to setup this experiment it is enough to take two sunglasses. IF you rotate one of the placed one behind the other glasses over 90° and at one moment can't see through, you own sunglasses with polarized surfaces.

That polarisers able to rotate light you will see by the next step of your experiment for which you need third - also polarized - glasses. Hold the two glasses in the position there do not let light through. Put the third glasses between the other two and not matter how you rotate this glasses, you will see through all three glasses.

The same experiment can be demonstrated with a swinging rope. Place two slits behind each other (let space between them), the slits both in the same way oriented, take a rope through the slit, fix it at one end and swing the rope, of course in the direction of the slits. Now rotate the second slit. The rope no more will swing behind the second slit. But now if you place a third slit between the other two slits and this under 45°. The rope will swing all other his length and by this the swinging direction will be rotated to 90°.

**Deflection of the light**

> light is oscillating magnetic and electric fields

I want to break this down to photons. Indeed photons have oscillating magnetic and electric field components. Suppose we could investigate a photon with vertically oscillating electric field and by this with horizontally oscillating magnetic field. An oszillation is than an electric field where at one moment the minus pole is directed up and the plus pole is directed down and after a moment they are located in the oppsite directions. The same with the magnetic field. At one moment the south pole is directed to the left and the north pole to the right and at the next moment they are directed in the opposite direction.

Sometimes you find this sketch;

[image]

but there is drawn only half of the fields.

A better sketch is this one:

[image]

> Would it require an electromagnet oscillating at the same frequency of the light to be bent?

No, an oscillating with the same frequency as the light electromagnet (for the photon's magnetic field component) or capacitor (for the electric field component) will not bend the trajectory. It will produce a wiggling trajectory and this is really done with *electrons* in a [free-electron laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-electron_laser)

[image]

Since the wavelength of light is around 600 nm (nanometers), the structure of of such bending device has to be of Nanometer scale. But that is what happens with light in your sunglasses.

To bend and not only to rotate light one use [diffractive optics](http://www.rpcphotonics.com/product/diffractive-optics/):

[image]

In the simplest case to bend light you use slits. Behind which you will see the famous fringes. Perhaps not in the sense you wanted, but you has bent the light.